# jQuery UI swap elements in different div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is to swap elements in different `div` elements. Here is my code: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehu7U/1/)

Each `div` can have only one dropped element. If `drop_` div has dropped element and droppable element is dropped from `#tire_deck` it has to be refused. If element is dropped from other `div` it has to be swapped. Can anybody help me to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to achive the result what I was looking for: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehu7U/9/), maybe it will be useful for somebody.

In draggable event I add `start` event to get it's original parent id:

```
            var parent_div_data;                        
            $(".tire").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                cursor: "move",
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: "invalid",
                start: function( event, ui ) {
                    parent_div_data = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                }
            });
```

Then in droppable `drop` event, I've checked how many draggable elements it has, and appended first element to second element's parent `div`

```
if($(this).find(".tire").length == 1){
                    var first = $(this).find(':first-child');
                    $('#' + parent_div_data).append(first);
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd go about it, is to store the draggable parent when the drag starts and then us it to determine wheter I'd swap the children or stop things.

This is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vvn5S/

And the javascript:

```
        $(function () {
            var origin;
            $(".tire").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                cursor: "move",
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: "invalid",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    origin = event.target.parentNode;
                }
            });
            $("#tire_deck").droppable({
                tolerance: "intersect",
                accept: ".tire",
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#tire_deck").append($(ui.draggable));
                }
            });
            $(".drop_1, .drop_2, .drop_3, .drop_4, .drop_5, .drop_6").droppable({
                tolerance: "intersect",
                accept: ".tire",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    if (this.children.length == 0) {
                        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
                    } else {
                        if (origin.id !== "tire_deck") {
                            event.stopPropagation();
                            var copyNode = $(this).children().detach();
                            $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
                            $(origin).append(copyNode);
                        } else {
                            alert("Stopped!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```